# Earth Engine: what is ee.Reducer.count() counting with partially covered pixels?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How is `ee.Reducer.count()` counting non-fully covered pixels (and likewise, for `ee.Reducer.histogram()`) ?

It seems there is an implicit minimum cell coverage, with pixels having only a small part inside the geometry being counted as 0? Is this correct, and what is the minimum threshold used? Did I miss something in the documentation?

Example below shows a simple geometry, that covers 3 pixels, at 27%, 49% and 74%:

- `ee.Reducer.count()` indicates only two pixels.
- `ee.Reducer.histogram().unweighted()` counts likewise only two, and seems to discard the pixel with only 27% coverage.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/14fafad3401721f5ef33543015b539ca

[image]

```
//////////////////
// import 
///////////////// 

var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-92.538634, 40.186573], [-92.538634, 40.186389], [-92.537857, 40.186389],
          [-92.537857, 40.186573]]], null, false);
var CDL_2015 = ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/2018')
  .select('cropland')


//////////////////
// Visu
/////////////////


// show
Map.centerObject(rectangle)
Map.addLayer(CDL_2015.clip(rectangle.buffer(10)), {}, "CDL_2015")
Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection(rectangle).style({width: 3, color: "blue", fillColor: "#00000000"}), {}, "CLU_here")


// get count


var count_W = CDL_2015.reduceRegion({
      geometry: rectangle,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), scale: 30});    

var count_noW = CDL_2015.reduceRegion({
      geometry: rectangle,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count().unweighted(), scale: 30});    
var hist_W = CDL_2015.reduceRegion({
      geometry: rectangle,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(), scale: 30});
var hist_noW = CDL_2015.reduceRegion({
      geometry: rectangle,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram().unweighted(), scale: 30});

print(count_W.get("cropland"), "Number pixels: (weighted)")
print(count_noW.get("cropland"), "Number pixels: unweighted?")

print(ee.Dictionary(hist_W.get("cropland")).get("histogram"), "histogram: (weighted)")
print(ee.Dictionary(hist_noW.get("cropland")).get("histogram"), "histogram: unweighted?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With unweighted reducers (e.g. count) pixels are included if their centroid is in the region.

See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region#pixels-in-the-region